# Is it possible in VB6 to hold its execution for getting a response?

Tags: vb6, wrapper, vb6-migration

I have a .NET web client which calls the VB dll through a wrapper. The VB dll holds a message box that needs to go to the .NET client and come back with a response. The VB6 dll should hold its execution until it receives a response and continue its execution.... How to achieve this?

Comment: Split the method A into two AA and AB. The first method AA returns the message to the .Net client. The .Net client then calls the second method AB, passing in the response from the user. If you need to store state between AA and AB, you could return the state in an object from AA and then pass it back in as an argument in AB.

Comment: We thought the same... 
Scenario 1: 
However What do I do If there are lot of local variables...within AA and how can I take them to AB? 
Scenario 2, 
How do I handle if Method A calls method B and method B Calls another method C (B and C are within VB dll) which holds a message but Method A is the one called from the WCF service.

Comment: Scenario 1. Put all the local variables in an object, return the object from AA, then pass the object back into AB. Scenario 2 Just return the message all the way back, C to B then B to A.

Comment: Scenario 2: Yes I can pass it up to the first caller, however I need to call the Method A again which might execute all the code again (not good eg: if any DB save) from a Service as the message needs to go to an Web UI.

Comment: Do u think it is possible through threading in VB6?

Comment: WEB UI --> WCf SERVICE --> VBDLL -->Msg
Msg needs to go to the WEB UI through service[which is not at all a problem]
Now based on the user response, we should somehow come back through the WCF service with the response and continue its execution (based on 'yes' or 'no')

Comment: @MarkJ Any suggestions further? Please your help as this part is getting tougher...